# How can I add application data or any data to the protractor-cucumber-report

Tags: protractor, cucumber, report

Want to display some application data or any data/string to the protractor-cucumber-report generated after execution.

I tried to import listener.Reporter same as I did for selenium-cucumber-report, and called
 "Reporter.addStepLog('some data')"; But this is not working on protractor-cucumber-framework.
In the generated report it should display the data/string.

**UPDATE - ADDING DEV-DEPENDENCIES**

```
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.802.0",
"@angular/cli": "~6.2.4",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.8",
"@angular/language-service": "^6.1.8",
"@types/jasmine": "^2.8.9",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
"@types/node": "^10.11.5",
"codelyzer": "^4.5.0",
"cucumber": "^5.0.3",
"jasmine": "^3.3.0",
"jasmine-core": "^3.2.1",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
"jasmine-xml-reporter": "^1.2.1",
"karma": "^3.0.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
"karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
"karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.3.1",
"karma-junit-reporter": "^1.2.0",
"nyc": "^13.1.0",
"protractor": "^5.4.1",
"protractor-cucumber-framework": "^6.1.1",
"rewire": "^4.0.1",
"ts-node": "~5.0.1",
"tslint": "^5.11.0",
"typescript": "^2.9.2"
},
```

Comment: Share the npm package name/url  and version that you used to generate report

Comment: npm version- 6.4.1 and protractor-cucumber-framework version - 6.1.1 . let me know if this is what you asked.

Comment: The nodejs package you used to generate report and its version. `protractor-cucumber-framework` is not the package I asked for.  A simple way is to share your package.json, i get the package from dependencies.

Comment: Updated with Dev-dependencies on query.

Comment: There are many packages for report, but no one is for cucumber report, please make sure you use correct package to generate cucumber report.

Comment: I am able to generate report on Jenkins server.  In conf.js file I have passed the format property as 'json:./cucumber-results.json' and I get .json report. So the plugin it is using to generate report is 'protractor-cucumber-framework'.  You can suggest me to use another plugin to generate report.